# Disable submit button until all hidden inputs have a value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a simple form with hidden inputs and I'm trying to check whether each hidden input has a value. If all hidden inputs have a value than disable or enable the submit button. The inputs are being filled once the user clicks on an image via jquery. Ive tried multiple ways and it seems like I'm missing something....

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">  
    <div class="selections" id="accordion">
        <h3>title<div class='status'>Pending</div></h3>
        <div class='select-form'>
            <div class='images'>
                <img src='images/vote.jpg' data-value='data-value'>
                <br/><span>title</span><br/>description
            </div>
            <input type='hidden' class='image-value' name='1' value=''>
        </div>
        <div class='select-form'>
            <div class='images'>
                <img src='images/vote.jpg' data-value='data-value2'>
                <br/><span>title</span><br/>description
            </div>
            <input type='hidden' class='image-value2' name='2' value=''>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" class="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

the javascript goes as follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $submit = $("input[type=submit]"),
        $inputs = $('input[type=hidden]');

    function checkEmpty() {

        // filter over the empty inputs

        return $inputs.filter(function() {
            return !$.trim(this.value);
        }).length === 0;
    }

    $inputs.on('blur', function() {
        $submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());
    }).blur(); // trigger an initial blur


});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try to debug the length of the filter and check what it gives you

Comment: Also I think that a final HTML would be better than PHP for us

Comment: Since you're using PHP it would be much easier to set disabled on the submit after you loop through the categories, than to use jquery blur on a hidden field which wouldn't work. Also in your PHP you have no value set for any of the hidden inputs. How would this work if they are always empty?

Comment: Thanks @PabloMatíasGomez simplified the code

Comment: @FunkDoc I edited the post, inputs are being filled using query once a user click on an image.

Comment: I would use the jQuery validation plugin for something like this - http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Oh, okay then wouldn't a simple jquery each() work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just call the `checkEmpty()` on `img.click()`, and from that function handle the disabled state.

Try it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dkbaocv/3/) (click the images)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $submit = $("input[type=submit]"),
        $inputs = $('input[type=hidden]');

    function checkEmpty() {
        var res = true;
        $inputs.each( function(i,v){
            if(v.value == ""){
                res = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

      $submit.prop("disabled", !res);    
    }

    $("img").click( function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type=hidden]").val("sdf");
        checkEmpty();
    });

    checkEmpty();  //set disabled onload
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trim function isn't behaving as you accept, remove it like [here :](http://jsfiddle.net/7yf2jhmb/)

```
function checkEmpty() {
    // filter over the empty inputs
    return inputs.filter(function() {
        return !(this.value);
    }).length === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside of the blur function to find out if all hidden inputs have a non empty value.

```
var empty=false;
$('input[type=hidden]').each(function(){
if($(this).val()==""){
empty=true;
}
});
if(empty){
//DISABLE SUBMIT
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using $ in your JavaScript variables when you shouldn't be. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keliix06/2f3cv2pk/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var submit = $("input[type=submit]"),
        inputs = $('input[type=hidden]');

    function checkEmpty() {

        // filter over the empty inputs

        return inputs.filter(function() {
            return !$.trim(this.value);
        }).length === 0;
    }

    inputs.on('blur', function() {
        submit.prop("disabled", !checkEmpty());
    }).blur(); // trigger an initial blur


});
```

Comment: JavaScript variables are allowed to begin with $ and is often used to distinguish between stored jQuery objects and other variables.